# Implementing radio buttons using realm getter function

Tags: java, android, realm

I am trying to use the following code to do radio buttons on dialog in Android.

I am wondering how I can use the following getTranslations to retrieve the list from realm to replace {" Easy "," Medium ",...} in CharSequence[] items so I can list the items from realm.  Thanks.

Getter function from realm:

```
public RealmList<Translation> getTranslations() {
    return Translations;
}
```

Translation Dialog Function with radio buttons:

```
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    Bundle bundle = getArguments();
    int position = bundle.getInt("position");
    final CharSequence[] items = {" Easy "," Medium "," Hard "} 

    AlertDialog.Builder b = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

    b.setTitle("English or Chinese names");
    b.setSingleChoiceItems(items, position, null);
    Log.d(tag, String.valueOf(items));
    b.setPositiveButton("OK",positiveListener);
    b.setNegativeButton("Cancel", null);
    AlertDialog d = b.create();
```

Answer (score 0):

i think the problem is that you use **final** :

```
final CharSequence[] items = {" Easy "," Medium "," Hard "}
```

*In the Java programming language, the* **final** *keyword is used in several different contexts to define an entity which may only be* **assigned once**.
*Once a final variable has been assigned, it always contains the same value.*

source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Final_%28Java%29

in addition you should think about that CharSequence is an interface

```
public interface CharSequence
```

*A CharSequence is a readable sequence of char values. This interface provides uniform, read-only access to many different kinds of char sequences. A char value represents a character in the Basic Multilingual Plane (BMP) or a surrogate. Refer to Unicode Character Representation for details.*

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/CharSequence.html

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just convert the RealmList to a primitive list? e.g.

```
public String[] getItems() {
  String[] items = new String[translations.size()];
  for (int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++) {
    items[i] = translations.get(i).getTitle();
  }
  return items;
}
```